# The derivative of a continuous and piecewise-differentiable CDF is a PDF

Tags: calculus, probability, random-variables

I'm taking a first course in Probability. We have now started discussing continuous random variables.
For a random variable $X$ we defined its PDF as the function $F_{X}$ such that $$\forall t\in\mathbb{R}:\;F_{X}(t)=\mathbb{P}(X\leq t).$$
We defined a probability density function as a non-negative integrable function $f_{X}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ that satisfies $$\forall a\in\mathbb{R}:\;F_{X}(a)=\int_{-\infty}^{a}f_{X}(t)dt$$
My professor posed the following theorem:

> Let $F_{X}$ be a continuous and piecewise-differentiable CDF for a random variable $X$, then $F_{X}'$ (with corrections to points where $F_{X}$ is not differentiable) is a PDF of $X$.

He said that this is a direct result of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. But for this to work we require $F_{X}'$ be **integrable**. Why must that be the case? There are counter examples of differentiable functions which are not integrable.
(Maybe this has to do with other properties of the PDF? It being right-continuous $\forall a\in\mathbb{R}$/increasing/bounded?)

Comment: What exactly is your question? A density must be integrable, by definition (as stated in your own post). If you want to claim that $F'_X$ is a density, then it at least must be integrable.

Comment: My question is whether or not it is obligatory for the derivative to be integrable for this to work, because its integrability wasn't required by the professor's theorem. Did he forget to mention that or does it work without that requirement?

Answer (score 1):

A (cumulative probability) [distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) can be defined wihout recourse to a density as a

- monotone increasing function $F:\mathbb R\to [0,1]$ that is
- continuous from the right, and
- has limits $F(-\infty)=0,F(+\infty)=1\,.$

If $F$ is even continuous and piecewise differentiable then, by the fundamental theorem of calculus,
$$\tag{1}
F(b)-F(a)=\int_a^bF'(t)\,dt
$$
for every open interval $(a,b)$ on which $F$ is differentiable. The definition of [piecewise differentiable](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Piecewise_Continuously_Differentiable_Function) includes that there is a *countable* collection of intervals $(a_n,b_n)$ such hat (1) holds and $\mathbb R\setminus\bigcup_n(a_n,b_n)$ is countable (the endpoints of those open intervals). Since that countable set is a set of Lebesgue measure zero  we can state that (1) holds for every interval $[a,b]\,.$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The page you linked to in your answer defines a piecewise continuously differentiable function, and your answer is correct if we assume $F_{X}$ is such a function. But we did not require $F_{X}$ to be a piecewise continuously differentiable function, but rather (1) **continuous**, and (2) **have a countable collection of intervals where it is differentiable**. What can we learn from properties (1) and (2) in regards to $F_{X}'$?

Comment: I did not find a link that better explains what *piecewise* exactly means. The emphasis is that it means a ***countable*** set of intervals. This applies to piecewise differentiable as well as piecewise continuously differntiable.

Comment: It being countable is clear to me, and I agree that once we can use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus this will work out. In my previous comment I wrote how the professor defined piecewise-differentiable. But how can we apply the fundamental theorem of calculus if the derivative isn't guaranteed to be integrable? Is there a generalized case where the derivative need not be integrable?

Comment: In greater generality, the distribution function must be _absolutely continuous_ to have a density.  (The fundamental theorem of calculus _characterizes_ absolutely continuous functions.) There are distributions whose density functions are not Riemann integrable, though: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.02273.pdf

Comment: @YiaWar . Good point. However, by Theorem 1 in [this script](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~const/bv.pdf) $F'$ exists almost everywhere and is integrable.